# How use multiple observable's results in subscriber

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

To be precise, here is an simple example(In real world, both observables are long running task):

```
Observable<String> city = Observable.just("Moscow");
//here i get hashcode based on result from city
Observable<Integer> hashCodeFromCity = city.flatMap(
        new Func1<String, Observable<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Integer> call(String s) {
        return  Observable.just(s.hashCode());
    }
});

hashCodeFromCity.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Integer integer) {
        //In subscriber I want to handle city and hashcode!
        System.out.println("Hashcode from !Moscow!: " + integer);

    }
});
```

How I can correctly consume city and hashcode together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building an `Observable<Integer>`, build an `Observable<MyPair>`. `MyPair` will be a class that will keep the hashcode and your object.

```
 class MyPair<T> {
       private final int hashCode;
       private final T value;
 }

 Observable.just("Moscou").map(city -> new MyPair<String>(city, city.hashCode()).subscribe(pair -> /** **/);
```

Comment: I upd question. In real world both observables are network tasks. Second task based on result from first.

Comment: The idea is the same. `asyncTask().flatMap(result -> asyncTask(result).map(result2 -> new MyPair(result, result2)).subscribe();`